# Changing Storage location of Influxdb running as a windows service

Tags: windows-services, influxdb

I am running running influxdb as a service on windows so the default directory for the data is (which is different than that mentioned in the config file and this is probably because I am running as a service)

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.influxdb\data
```

Is there any way to change the storage location? For example if I want the data to be stored in `C:\Programfiles\Data` can I make this work? Or more generally can you change the storage location of a windows service?

Comment: How have you configured it to run as a service? NSSM?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually i used NSSM to make it run as a serive. But couldnt find where I can change the storage location of the data from the default one for services. Is there a way to configure that using NSSM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to change this on my system by setting the `dir` entry of the `[data]` section of influxdb.conf. For example:

```
dir = "/Influx/InfluxDB/.influxdb/data"
```

Puts my data directory in `C:\Influx\InfluxDB\.influxdb\data`.

FYI the reason it ends up in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.influxdb\data` by default when running it as a service is because you are running the service as the `Local System` identity. Another way to change the location is to run the service as a specific named user, after which the default location for the data will be `c:\Users\<username>\.influxdb\data\`.

Comment: It doesnt work for me. So lets I run Influx db by typing in command prompt "influxd.exe -config influxdb.conf" after changing the dir in the [data] section of the config fiel. In that case everything works perfectly together with all changes I do in the config file (for example I also enabled authentication in the config file). Now lets say I disconnect from influxdb and then start it from the service manager (btw I used NSSM to run influxdb as a service). In this case it seems that it doesnt read the config file since the storage place doesnt change and also authentication doesnt work.

Comment: Also it seems that its running another instance of influxdb since when I write show databases the databases are different from the case when I run influxdb manually from the command prompt....

Comment: If you change the data location you'll need to copy your existing /data folder contents to the new location. When you use nssm to setup your service, include the `-config infludb.conf` part as an argument (i'd suggest putting in the full path to the config to be sure also).

Comment: Oh I was missing that i have to include the config in the argument part in NSSM... Thank you, now everything is working well!

Answer (score -1):

Check this so-hard-to-find-thing out, please: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/administration/config/#data-settings-data

Comment: Did you actually read the question before answering?! If you dont run influxdb as a service then you can use the config file to change the storage location without any problem... But when you run as a windows service it doesn't work anymore. It stores all data in C:\Windows\System32\config and I am unable to change this using the config file... So basically I couldn't find out how to change the storage location of an application running as a service on windows.